# Adding sublists into one list as lists elements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, data-structures

I'm looking for a way to sum up my output of list. I want to add each output of this for loop into one "big" list as a single list element.

```
for line in f.split('\n'):

    words = line.split()
```

How do I achieve this:

```
L1 = [1,2,3]
L2 = [4,5,6]
L3 = [7,8,9]
SumList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Comment: `sum_list = [ line.split() for line in f.split('\n') ]`

Comment: at some point a cast to `float` would also be needed, like `[list(map(float, line.split())) for line in f.split('\n') ]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can append `str.split` list to another list

**Ex:**

```
res = []
for line in f.split('\n'):
    res.append(line.split())
```

Or  **use list comprehension**

**Ex:**

```
print([line.split() for line in f.split('\n')])
```